# iterate through If statment checking checkboxs in vba word

Tags: vba, loops, dynamic, checkbox, ms-word

I have a code that works to check singel checkbox

```
Sub check_if_checked()
    If CheckBox1.Value Then
        MsgBox "checked"
    Else
        MsgBox "not checked"
    End If
End Sub
```

What i want to do is to create a loop where in the if statment i can replace the check box number with the loop iteration variable.

Something like

```
If "CheckBox" & i.Value Then
```

Can this be done or maybe done a diffrent way?

Answer (score 0):

In the below example I have 4 Check Boxes with the following names `CheckBox1`, `CheckBox2`, `CheckBox3`, `CheckBox4`.

```
Sub check_if_checked()
  Dim i As Integer
  i = 1
  Do While i <= 4
    If (IsNull(Me("CheckBox" & i).value)) Then _
      MsgBox ("CheckBox" & i & " is Null") Else _
      MsgBox (Me("CheckBox" & i).value)
    i = i + 1
  Loop
End Sub
```

Or the following may work for you:

```
Sub check_if_checked()
  Dim TempCntrl As Control

  For Each TempCntrl In UserForm1.Controls
    If TempCntrl.Name Like "CheckBox*" Then
      MsgBox (TempCntrl.Name & ":  " & TempCntrl.value)
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: When i try running that code i get the error "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"

Comment: try just the following inside of the Do While: `MsgBox (Me("CheckBox" & i).value)`     `i = i + 1`.  If that does not work then let me know where it is erroring out.

Comment: Still getting:
"Compile error:
Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"